# Grails on linux problem: provider for SAXParserFactory can not be found

Tags: java, linux, grails

Running a recently started Grails (1.3.1) application fails on both our linux machines (Bamboo server & laptop) with the exception "Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found". This both using maven or standalone. On our OS X and Windows developments machines using JDK 1.6_020 the problem does not occur.

When using the `-Djaxp.debug=1` VM parameter the log shows that no specific `SAXParserFactoryImpl` implementation is chosen, and that fallback value `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl` is used.

JDK 1.6_020 on the linux machine does indeed contain `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl` in one of its .jar files. However running grails fails with `javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found`

Any clues on how to find the exact cause for this problem are welcome.

Thx,
Ruben

**Environment:**

- Grails 1.3.1 (build with Maven or standalone)
- Sun JDK 1.6_020 or Sun JDK 1.6_014
- Ubuntu (recent version)

**Partial stack trace from Bamboo:**

```
    Embedded error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to start Grails
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to start Grails
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:285)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:194)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.MvnCompileMojo.execute(MvnCompileMojo.java:41)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildHelper.execute(GrailsBuildHelper.java:119)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:277)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildHelper.execute(GrailsBuildHelper.java:113)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.xml.FactorySupport$2.run(FactorySupport.java:56)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.xml.FactorySupport.createFactory(FactorySupport.java:33)
    at groovy.xml.FactorySupport.createSaxParserFactory(FactorySupport.java:54)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.<init>(XmlSlurper.java:97)
    at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.<init>(XmlSlurper.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
```

Comment: This was caused by combining the dependency management in Maven (excluding several dependencies) and Grails.

No exact cause was identified since upgrading to Grails 1.3.2 resolved this problem, while introducing a few other dependency issues.